# selecting <li> with :first jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this **HTML** which every 5 second the class **display** will pass in next `<li>`

```
<ul class="listing">
  <li class="display"><img src="first"></li>
  <li class=""><img src="second"></li>
  <li class=""><img src="third"></li>
</ul>

<div class="put"></div>
```

and have this **SCRIPT**

```
var q = jQuery(".listing").children(".display");
var w = jQuery(q).prev("li").find("img").attr("src");
var e = jQuery(q).first();
var r = jQuery(".listing > li").last().find("img").attr("src");

if(e){
  jQuery(".put").css({"background-image":"url(" + r + ")"});
}else{
  jQuery(".put").css({"background-image":"url(" + w + ")"});
}
```

I want to get the **PREVIOUS** image src of `<li>` that has the class **display** and put it in `<div>` and make it a *background-image*

but if the first `<li>` has the class `display` I want to display the last image.

ps. im sorry i forgot to put the previous

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail?

Comment: Is it possible to add id with your <li> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet.

```js
var isFirst = $('.listing li').first().hasClass('display');
var src;
if(isFirst)
{
  src = $('.listing li').last().find('img').attr('src');
}
else
{
  src = $('.listing li:eq('+parseInt($('.listing li.display').index()-1)+')').find('img').attr('src')
}
console.log("THIS SRC WILL BE SET   " + src);
$(".put").css({"background-image":"url(" + src + ")"});

console.log("NOW DIV HAS NEW SRC   " + $('.put').css('background-image'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listing">
  <li class="display"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x50"></li>
  <li class=""><img src="https://placehold.it/350x75"></li>
  <li class=""><img src="https://placehold.it/350x100"></li>
</ul>

<div class="put">DIV with Background Image</div>
```

Comment: so should I replace it in **var e**?

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization Can you show me your jsfiddle which change the display class every 5 seconds.

Comment: it is a slider in fact i just give the simple code of it

Comment: What exact problem you're facing ? When the first li has display class then you want to show it's image to put div ?

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization : try my answer, I've created snippet for your to achieve what you're looking for

Comment: I want to display the previous image into div and make it a background-image but the first <li> dont have previous so I will display the last  <li> image instead

Comment: That's what this code is doing, did you tried ?, Right now it's showing last src (350x100) because first div has the class "display"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123500/discussion-between-loading-and-pure-rhymer-organization).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.listing li.display').each(function(this){
this.hide();
});

$('.listing li.display').first().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, please note that the variable `w` is undefined as there is no previous element in the list. the variable `e` is same as variable `q`. Could you please explain in more detail on what you are trying to achieve. If it is about hiding/showing images, I would recommend the solution like what Nitya Kumar suggested.

Comment: no just get the attr of src to the `<li>` that has the class of display

Answer (score 1):

You first get the element with the `display` class and if it has then get the image using `html()` to replace the current image and then you can use `setInterval()` to repeat the code after every 5 seconds:

```
var e;
setInterval(function(){
  e = $('.listing').find('.display');
  $('.put').html(e.html());
  //change elememt class
  console.log(e.next('li').length)
  if(e.next('li').length){
   e.removeClass('display').next('li').addClass('display');
  }else{
   e.removeClass('display');
   e = $('.listing').children().first('li').addClass('display');
  }
}, 5000)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnfcm674/1/)

Answer (score 1):

check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bugc6w3y/
What you need to do is check the index o f both the elements:

```
var q = jQuery(".listing").children(".display");
var w = jQuery(q).prev("li").find("img").attr("src");
var e = jQuery('li').first();
var r = jQuery(".listing > li").last().find("img").attr("src");

var q1 = jQuery( "li" ).index( q ); 
var e1 = jQuery( "li" ).index( e ); 

if(e1==q1) {
  jQuery(".put").css({"background-image":"url(" + r + ")"});
}else{
  jQuery(".put").css({"background-image":"url(" + w + ")"});
}
```